# Why is this question not closed as offtopic for being a tools to use question?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, questions, closed-questions, off-topic

Why does this question not fall under the "off-topic" category, being a tools to use question? The question is:

[What are some alternatives to ReSharper?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2834439/what-are-some-alternatives-to-resharper)

Comment: Because it was asked in 2010, and the new rules are enforced recently

Comment: Please include your actual question in your question body, not just in the title.

Comment: And said question got closed 2 minutes after this was posted. An effective way to get a question closed I suppose.

Comment: And what's about similar one: [Tool to optimize C# using statements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/136001/tool-to-optimize-c-sharp-using-statements/136007#136007). It it because it's not "Questions about general computing hardware and software" and is more specific to development software, or just also they forgotten to mark it as such one?

Comment: @Agat As per my answer: "Regardless, when you see a question that should be closed that isn't just vote/flag to close. There's no need to bring every single one of them up on meta."  Meta simply can't scale well enough for everyone to post requests for closure here.

Comment: Every single? Hm... I've reviewed already about 20 ones today... Have I missed where I did mention them in Meta?! If I did, then sorry, of course.

Comment: I am voting to close this question as off-topic as it concerns *one specific site* on the Stack Exchange network. See: [Why are questions only about one site in the network considered off-topic here?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/355783)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It *does*.  It simply wasn't closed.  There are plenty of questions that aren't closed that should be, for any number of reasons.  They could have just not drawn the attention of people who could close them, they could have been posted before the given guideline was created, the question could have been edited to change it's appropriateness, it could have been improperly reopened, etc.

Regardless, when you see a question that should be closed that isn't just vote/flag to close.  There's no need to bring every single one of them up on meta.