# The [tools] tag is too ambiguous. Let's burninate it

Tags: discussion, status-completed, meta, burninate-request

The [tools](/questions/tagged/tools) tag has 27 questions, and while it *does* have a tag wiki, it doesn't cover all of the various questions tagged with it. Its [most recently posted question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/204476/622284) was asked 7 years ago.

The questions tagged with [tools](/questions/tagged/tools) appear to be either related to the [10k-tools](/questions/tagged/10k-tools), various [moderator-tools](/questions/tagged/moderator-tools), hardware tools, tools related to software, or [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)s that desire a new tool. It's very ambiguous, and it is not immediately apparent to any new poster what it is for.

One thing these questions have in common is that the [tools](/questions/tagged/tools) tag is entirely irrelevant to the body of the post, or is covered by the other tags they have. The [one case](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50792/what-tool-is-used-for-this-q-a-site) where the [tools](/questions/tagged/tools) tag is the only tag present is a case where it could be entirely replaced with [technology](/questions/tagged/technology). <sub><sup>(Except [this case](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30441/heres-a-stackoverflow-monitoring-script-to-get-new-questions-asap), but it should honestly be on Stack Apps. I have voted to close it and it is now closed via review.)</sup></sub>

There *is* a [FAQ question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10369/which-tools-and-technologies-are-used-to-build-the-stack-exchange-network) tagged with [tools](/questions/tagged/tools), but the meaning behind the tag in this question's context appears to be completely covered by the wiki for [technology](/questions/tagged/technology) (which it also has.)

Given that it's entirely ambiguous (between 10k tools, moderator tools, newly proposed tools for users, or the tools Stack Exchange use to develop the site), I'm suggesting that this tag be [burninated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120640/what-does-it-mean-to-burninate-a-tag). The tag fails all of the tests described in the [When to burninate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239191/364003) guidance.

What are your thoughts? Is there a better alternative?

Comment: We have the [tools] to burninate this tag.

Comment: Hmm, I missed this question. I have "fixed" the missing tag wiki but that might not be the wisest thing to do, in hindsight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[tools](/questions/tagged/tools) is no more.

[image]

A good few people helped to close and/or delete a lot of the questions previously tagged with [tools](/questions/tagged/tools) as they were either off-topic, duplicates, or otherwise old and not useful. The remainder were kept around and retagged accordingly. Thanks to all of you who helped pitch in!